# Error in Laravel Test when I tried to logout an logged user:

Tags: testing, phpunit, laravel-9

I'm facing some problem when I attempt to run a test for know if a user can do logout properly. I'm stuck since one day ago and I can't find the answer in any place.

I'm calling to the `route('api.logout')` the response is a `500` error and the error says I'm trying to using the method `delete()` on `null`.

This is my test file:

```php
namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AuthControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, WithoutMiddleware;

    private array $userData;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->userData = [
            'email' => 'admin@mydomain.com',
            'password' => '12345633',
            'password_confirmation' => '12345633',
            'name' => 'admin',
            'remember_me' => true
        ];
    }

    public function test_can_register_a_user(): void
    {
        $response = $this->post(route('api.register'), $this->userData);
        $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
        $content = $response->json();
        $this->assertNotNull($content['id']);
    }
    public function test_can_login_a_user(): void
    {
        $this->test_can_register_a_user();
        $response = $this->post(route('api.login', $this->userData));
        $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
        $content = $response->json();
        $this->assertNotNull($content['id']);
    }
    public function test_can_logout_a_user(): void
    {
        $this->test_can_login_a_user();
        $user = User::where('email', '=', $this->userData['email'])->first();
        $this->actingAs($user);
        $response = $this->delete(route('api.logout'));
        $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

This is my logout function in the controller:

```php
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $user->currentAccessToken()->delete();
}
```

Also I tried doing a `Session::start()` in `test_can_logout_a_user` and using `$this->be` instead of `actingAs`, but nothing works for me. The `$user` exists but it doesn't have any tokens. If I run `$user->tokens()` I got `0` tokens.

I'm using `SQLITE` type of database and `:memory:` in the `phpunit.xml`.

It works fine when I use `POSTMAN` or `INSOMNIA`, but it doesn't work when I'm running that test.

Thank you very much.

---

I'm using Sanctum for authentication

---

This seems to be a problem with Laravel 9 and Sanctum. I've updated the code in the test and logout function

```
public function test_can_logout_a_user(): void
    {
        $user = User::create($this->userData);
        $token = $user->createToken('Test token')->plainTextToken;
        $response = $this->json('DELETE', route('api.auth.logout'), [], ['Authorization' => "Bearer $token"]);
        $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;
.
.
.
.  
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $accessToken = $request->bearerToken();
        $token = PersonalAccessToken::findToken($accessToken);
        $token->delete();
    }
```

Comment: Clearly the user does not have a token, that is why you get "trying to using the method `delete()` on `null`". So, I have no idea if you are using Sanctum, or what type of authentication, but you need to have a token available at that instance... I would recommend 100% to move the creation of the user inside each test, you will have less issues in the future... saying this from 10+ years of experience

Comment: I'm using Sanctum  for authentication.
The strange fact is when I do this request from an external resource to Laravel, it works properly. :( For example Postman, Insomnia or JS. There is a token present.

Comment: That works because you may have an existing (correctly) created and logged in user (what I mean is that, maybe, you are creating a token when the user logs in, etc)

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Laravel 9 and Sanctum. I changed my test and logout function.
Thank you very much. I will update the code.

Comment: I don't think it is an issue, having a user (`actingAs($user)`) does not mean it will have a token, just that the user exists and was able to log in

Comment: You're right about this, but also If I logined in previously, and then I did $request->user()->tokens() I got no tokens. In previous versions, it returned a collection of tokens. But, may be I used another Authentication system, who knows...

Comment: Sadly I never tested Sanctum or any other authentication package (appart from just doing `actingAs`), so I do not know how you should exactly set it up, nor if in the past you would get tokens or not and maybe now it is different

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It must have been my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In your test you use the `WithoutMiddleware` meaning and you disable part of the code which you should test and runs in all other cases (postman, insomnia) . Why you need that? You can disabled specifice middlewares with the `withoutMiddleware(['name_of_middleware'])` but for the login process i don't recomment it.